# How to give all previous pivot points labels

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I have this Script calculating Pivot points in V5 Pinescript:

```
//@version=5

indicator(title='Pivot Point', shorttitle='Pivot Point', overlay=true)
timeframe = input('D', title='Timeframe')
width = input.int(2, minval=1)
xHigh  = request.security(syminfo.ticker,timeframe, high[1], barmerge.gaps_off, barmerge.lookahead_on)
xLow   = request.security(syminfo.ticker,timeframe, low[1], barmerge.gaps_off, barmerge.lookahead_on)
xClose = request.security(syminfo.ticker,timeframe, close[1], barmerge.gaps_off, barmerge.lookahead_on)
xOpen = request.security(syminfo.ticker, timeframe, open[1], barmerge.gaps_off, barmerge.lookahead_on)

X = close
vBC = close
vPP = close
vTC = close
vR1 = close
vS1 = close
vR2 = close
vS2 = close
vR3 = close
vS3 = close
vR4 = close
vS4 = close

vPP := (xHigh + xLow + xClose) / 3
vBC := (xHigh + xLow) / 2.0
vTC := vPP - vBC + vPP
vR1 := vPP + vPP - xLow
vS1 := vPP - (xHigh - vPP)
vR2 := vPP + xHigh - xLow
vS2 := vPP - (xHigh - xLow)
vR3 := xHigh + 2 * (vPP - xLow)
vS3 := xLow - 2 * (xHigh - vPP)

plot(vTC, color=color.new(#ffffff, 0), title='TC', style=plot.style_circles, linewidth=width)
plot(vPP, color=color.new(#ffffff, 0), title='PP', style=plot.style_circles, linewidth=width)
plot(vBC, color=color.new(#ffffff, 0), title='BC', style=plot.style_circles, linewidth=width)
plot(vS1, color=color.new(#ff88a5, 0), title='S1', style=plot.style_circles, linewidth=width)
plot(vS2, color=color.new(#ff6309, 0), title='S2', style=plot.style_circles, linewidth=width)
plot(vS3, color=color.new(#ff0000, 0), title='S3', style=plot.style_circles, linewidth=width)
plot(vR1, color=color.new(#aef6ff, 0), title='R1', style=plot.style_circles, linewidth=width)
plot(vR2, color=color.new(#14b6df, 0), title='R2', style=plot.style_circles, linewidth=width)
plot(vR3, color=color.new(#6164ff, 0), title='R3', style=plot.style_circles, linewidth=width)
plotshape(vPP, color=na, text="Std_PP", textcolor=color.new(#ffffff, 0), location=location.absolute, show_last=1, title="Fibonacci Text, don't change", offset=-1)
plotshape(vR1, color=na, text="Std_R1", textcolor=color.new(#aef6ff, 0), location=location.absolute, show_last=1, title="Fibonacci Text, don't change", offset=-1)
plotshape(vR2, color=na, text="Std_R2", textcolor=color.new(#14b6df, 0), location=location.absolute, show_last=1, title="Fibonacci Text, don't change", offset=-1)
plotshape(vR3, color=na, text="Std_R3", textcolor=color.new(#6164ff, 0), location=location.absolute, show_last=1, title="Fibonacci Text, don't change", offset=-1)
plotshape(vS1, color=na, text="Std_S1", textcolor=color.new(#ff88a5, 0), location=location.absolute, show_last=1, title="Fibonacci Text, don't change", offset=-1)
plotshape(vS2, color=na, text="Std_S2", textcolor=color.new(#ff6309, 0), location=location.absolute, show_last=1, title="Fibonacci Text, don't change", offset=-1)
plotshape(vS3, color=na, text="Std_S3", textcolor=color.new(#ff0000, 0), location=location.absolute, show_last=1, title="Fibonacci Text, don't change", offset=-1)
```

My Script only show the labels for the last pivot only, I wanted the script to give label also to the previous pivot, How can I do this? i tried to change the `show_last` number but it didn't work well, it just gives a bunch of overlay texts in the last pivots

Example of Current Pivot:

[image]

Without Show last:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a workaround I am able to make this happen, on a beginning of a session with this boolean functions for every timeframes:

```
barstate_start_session() =>
    if timeframe.period == "240" and ((hour(time, syminfo.timezone) == 02))
        true
    else if timeframe.period == "180" and ((hour(time, syminfo.timezone) == 01))
        true
    else if timeframe.period == "120" and ((hour(time, syminfo.timezone) == 22))
        true
    else if timeframe.period == "60" and ((hour(time, syminfo.timezone) == 2))
        true
    else if timeframe.period == "45" and ((hour == 1 and minute == 0))
        true
    else if timeframe.period == "30" and ((hour == 0 and minute == 0))
        true
    else if timeframe.period == "15" and ((hour == 23 and minute == 0) or barstate.islast) 
        true
    else if timeframe.period == "5" and ((hour == 22 and minute == 0) or barstate.islast)
        true
    else if timeframe.period == "3" and ((hour == 22 and minute == 0) or barstate.islast)
        true
    else if timeframe.period == "1" and ((hour == 22 and minute == 0) or barstate.islast)
        true
    else
        false
```

this will filter the text appearing for every dots, and hence this is all good when you apply it to the plotshape:

```
plotshape(barstate_start_session() ? vR1 : na, color=na, text="Std_R1", textcolor=color.new(#aef6ff, 0), location=location.absolute, title="Fibonacci Text, don't change", offset=-1)
plotshape(barstate_start_session() ? vR2 : na, color=na, text="Std_R2", textcolor=color.new(#14b6df, 0), location=location.absolute, title="Fibonacci Text, don't change", offset=-1)
plotshape(barstate_start_session() ? vR3 : na, color=na, text="Std_R3", textcolor=color.new(#6164ff, 0), location=location.absolute, title="Fibonacci Text, don't change", offset=-1)
plotshape(barstate_start_session() ? vS1 : na, color=na, text="Std_S1", textcolor=color.new(#ff88a5, 0), location=location.absolute, title="Fibonacci Text, don't change", offset=-1)
plotshape(barstate_start_session() ? vS2 : na, color=na, text="Std_S2", textcolor=color.new(#ff6309, 0), location=location.absolute, title="Fibonacci Text, don't change", offset=-1)
plotshape(barstate_start_session() ? vS3 : na, color=na, text="Std_S3", textcolor=color.new(#ff0000, 0), location=location.absolute, title="Fibonacci Text, don't change", offset=-1)
```

NOTE: the boolean functions is accustomized to my local time (GMT+7)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can delete the plotshape (it is just title and will draw a lot of information).
And then you will see your all your pivot.

Here an example of your daily pivot in a 4 hours timeframe :

[image]

the code :

```
//@version=5

indicator(title='Pivot Point', shorttitle='Pivot Point', overlay=true)
timeframe = input('D', title='Timeframe')
width = input.int(2, minval=1)
xHigh  = request.security(syminfo.ticker,timeframe, high[1], barmerge.gaps_off, barmerge.lookahead_on)
xLow   = request.security(syminfo.ticker,timeframe, low[1], barmerge.gaps_off, barmerge.lookahead_on)
xClose = request.security(syminfo.ticker,timeframe, close[1], barmerge.gaps_off, barmerge.lookahead_on)
xOpen = request.security(syminfo.ticker, timeframe, open[1], barmerge.gaps_off, barmerge.lookahead_on)

X = close
vBC = close
vPP = close
vTC = close
vR1 = close
vS1 = close
vR2 = close
vS2 = close
vR3 = close
vS3 = close
vR4 = close
vS4 = close

vPP := (xHigh + xLow + xClose) / 3
vBC := (xHigh + xLow) / 2.0
vTC := vPP - vBC + vPP
vR1 := vPP + vPP - xLow
vS1 := vPP - (xHigh - vPP)
vR2 := vPP + xHigh - xLow
vS2 := vPP - (xHigh - xLow)
vR3 := xHigh + 2 * (vPP - xLow)
vS3 := xLow - 2 * (xHigh - vPP)

plot(vTC, color=color.new(#ffffff, 0), title='TC', style=plot.style_circles, linewidth=width)
plot(vPP, color=color.new(#ffffff, 0), title='PP', style=plot.style_circles, linewidth=width)
plot(vBC, color=color.new(#ffffff, 0), title='BC', style=plot.style_circles, linewidth=width)
plot(vS1, color=color.new(#ff88a5, 0), title='S1', style=plot.style_circles, linewidth=width)
plot(vS2, color=color.new(#ff6309, 0), title='S2', style=plot.style_circles, linewidth=width)
plot(vS3, color=color.new(#ff0000, 0), title='S3', style=plot.style_circles, linewidth=width)
plot(vR1, color=color.new(#aef6ff, 0), title='R1', style=plot.style_circles, linewidth=width)
plot(vR2, color=color.new(#14b6df, 0), title='R2', style=plot.style_circles, linewidth=width)
plot(vR3, color=color.new(#6164ff, 0), title='R3', style=plot.style_circles, linewidth=width)
//plotshape(vPP, color=na, text="Std_PP", textcolor=color.new(#ffffff, 0), location=location.absolute, title="Fibonacci Text, don't change", offset=-1)
//plotshape(vR1, color=na, text="Std_R1", textcolor=color.new(#aef6ff, 0), location=location.absolute,  title="Fibonacci Text, don't change", offset=-1)
//plotshape(vR2, color=na, text="Std_R2", textcolor=color.new(#14b6df, 0), location=location.absolute,  title="Fibonacci Text, don't change", offset=-1)
//plotshape(vR3, color=na, text="Std_R3", textcolor=color.new(#6164ff, 0), location=location.absolute,  title="Fibonacci Text, don't change", offset=-1)
//plotshape(vS1, color=na, text="Std_S1", textcolor=color.new(#ff88a5, 0), location=location.absolute, title="Fibonacci Text, don't change", offset=-1)
//plotshape(vS2, color=na, text="Std_S2", textcolor=color.new(#ff6309, 0), location=location.absolute,  title="Fibonacci Text, don't change", offset=-1)
//plotshape(vS3, color=na, text="Std_S3", textcolor=color.new(#ff0000, 0), location=location.absolute,  title="Fibonacci Text, don't change", offset=-1)
```

NB : if you uncomment the lasts lines, you have the title :
[image]

Comment: Umm, actually i wanted the title to appear to all previous pivots, the pivot is working well before, i use this plotshape to actually draw what i want (but currently its doing only to last pivots), I just wanted to add title for learning & backtesting purpose..

Comment: although its simple to just looking at it now (S1 S2 S3 R1 R2 R3) is in visible gap,  the reason i need to add title is that there are also another method pivots like fibonacci, camarilla that i wanted to put together to this, so it be helpful if the labels are applied to all previous plots

Comment: Just delete the '//' at the end of the code of my answer, all the title will be drawn

Comment: i applied your code, but it resulted the above pictures in my case..

Comment: I add the picture with the code uncommented, where you get the titles

Comment: oh i see, so its actually show the label for every dot.. thats why its very crowded in lower timeframe.. i would really like that the label is shown only to the last dot but for every previous label.. (if it were possible)